# My style is not rendering in Tailwindcss. Can someone help me understand the cause of this?

Tags: html, css, terminal, styles

So, can anyone tell me why tailwind fails to render any changes or apply the style after a while. In the image below I changed the background of the div to red; however, the change did not take affect. More importantly the content of the page does not display as it should.

I have updated VS Code, I have had this problem in Webstorm as well. I closed and opened the terminal. Closed and opened the the application. Updated and restart my computer, on two different computers. This happens when I create a whole new folder and create a a new file and write the code from scratch like here in folder "test2".

It seems to stop rebuilding after a while.
I am not sure what the solution to this is. Can someone please help me solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: An update: 
The --watch only works/rebuilds for the index.html file but not the other files that I need to link to for the webpage.

Comment: second update: I solved the problem by adding the file to the content section of the tailwind config file *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

second update: I solved the problem by adding the file to the content section of the tailwind config file *sigh*